A movie in which a modern-day tank crew gets teleported into the Middle Ages
I am trying to track down a movie for which I saw an ad many years ago (guessing in the early 2000s).
In the TV ad, a modern day tank crew were engaged in combat, and somehow get transported back into the Middle Ages while preparing to fire. They end up between two armies preparing to fight, and fire off a round to the amazement of the soldiers in that era.
That's all I remember of that commercial/trailer, does anybody have any idea? I tried finding it online but with no success.
It was an American movie (I remember their accents), if that's any help.
I saw the ad in Romania, so the movie might have been released some years before the moment I saw the ad. Plus I saw it on a channel that often aired pretty good movies, even lesser-known ones.

Added some info about that, I saw it in Romania. Remembered that TV ad a few days ago after talking to someone and I now realise how hard it is to track down such an old/little known movie.

Romania, eh? Was it Pro Cinema or Acasa gold?

Pro Cinema, yep.

And you're 100% sure about all these details? (That it was a tank, that it was the Middle Ages, that it was a feature length film etc.?)

Yes, there aren't many details I remember, but the ones I do I'm sure about.

Was the tank an M1-Abrams or did it look different?

Yes, M1-Abrams or something very, very similar.

Just a guess, but might it have been G.I. Samurai:

On their way to a manoeuver, a wildly mixed group of Japanese soldiers with a tank, an APC, a patrol boat and a helicopter suddenly find themselves stranded 400 years in the past and under attack by samurai forces. Their designated leader, Lieutenant Yoshiaki Iba (Sonny Chiba), befriends and joins forces with Nagao Kagetora, the war leader of lord Koizumi. Seeing the stranded soldiers' war machinery in action, Kagetora persuades Iba to aid him in his struggle for supremacy in Japan.


It's close, but I forgot to note it was an American movie by the actor's accents. From what I remember there was just this crew and their tank transported into the past. But thank you very much for your suggestion!

The more recent Heaven's Soldiers has a similar plot, but it's Korean (and no tank).
